# How to read a line a seperate (+, -) from numbers in C

Tags: c, function, line, call

I'm trying to write a program that will read a line like:
* 3 2

then call up a function multiply that I have written that will do the equation.

I've got the formulas for all the operations, just don't know how to seperate the line and make the calls.

Comment: Probably want to take a look at scanf. [(link)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: If you're looking for a desk calculator, Bjarne Stroustrup writes a version of one in the book "The C++ Programming language" to show code before the change to modularity, and it's pretty much a C program.

Answer (score 0):

[Polish (prefix) notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) is when an operator is written before its operands, like you have here. If each of your lines corresponds to a "Polish sentence", and if you're able to conveniently store an entire line in memory (very likely, I'd guess), then the simplest way might be to just read the entire line into a buffer (i.e., with `fgets()`), then use `strtok()` to build an array of pointers to each token, and finally traverse that array from its end to its start (basically reading the sentence from right to left), processing each token in a manner similar to the pseudocode given in the aforementioned Wikipedia entry. (The *left-to-right* processing of a [*reverse* Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) sentence is exactly the same and arguably a bit easier to understand, simply because one doesn't have to traverse the sentence backwards to do it so easily.)